# How can I display Unity games in Flex?

Tags: unity, browser-based-games, flex

We have tried the following methods to upload sample Unity3D build to a desktop application in Flex: HTML Loader, NavigateToURL, iFrame and resolvePath.

But we only see the text content, not the 3D content. What is the solution for that? How can I host a Unity game inside Flex? [image]

Comment: The Unity web player depends on a plugin that likely isn't available in the Flex browser. I don't think there is a solution for making this work.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Unity can already deploy desktop applications directly; deploying a web build and packaging that as a desktop app is pretty roundabout.

Comment: But I want to display the unity build into flex platform

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, as things are of now, **you can't run Unity3D content in flex**.

There is simply not enough Flex users for Unity to support it with their plugin.

However, there are some hope coming in Unity 5, since it will be possible (at least promised) to build games that run straight with WebGL, discarding the need for a Unity Web player plugin (at least for most projects)

Until then, I would say that the odds of Unity making a plugin for Flex in this "mid transition period" is very unlikely.

Comment: Thanku for ur kind information... http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/04/29/on-the-future-of-web-publishing-in-unity/